# Re-size bar graph according to number of charts

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have developed VBA code that uses a user input to creates a bar chart. The number of bars in this chart can vary from the different users inputs. Unfortunatly I cannot think of a way to alter the size of the chart according to the number of bars.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestion on how to do this.

Comment: I posted a potential answer to your question. Did you have time to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you want to make a change with VBA and you don't know where to start from you can try to [record a macro](https://wellsr.com/vba/excel/recording-a-macro/) while you perform the action manually and then check the generated code to see the output.

For example, if I select a chart inside a sheet and resize it, I get the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleHeight 1.5, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

You can then use this as a hint of how to write your code. For instance, you can make the scaling factor depend on the number of bars instead of being fixed at 1.5 in the example above.

Or, even better, instead of scaling the chart, you can specify the dimensions directly using the `Height` and `Width` properties:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Height = 300
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Width = 100 + NumberOfBars * 15
```

#### Using the ChartArea object

The down side of the code above is that you need the name of the shape. If you want to edit the size of a chart that is currently selected without knowing its name, you could also use the following that makes use of the `Height` and `Width` properties:

```
Dim chrtArea As ChartArea
Set chrtArea = Selection
chrtArea.Height = 300
chrtArea.Width = 100 + NumberOfBars * 15
```

Or alternatively, you could assign the `chrt` variable as you create it which would make your code even more reliable.

#### How to get the number of bars?

Assuming you have only one series of data, you can get the number of observations which will be the number of bars:

```
Dim NumberOfBars As Long
NumberOfBars = UBound(chrtArea.Parent.SeriesCollection(1).XValues)
```